# chatserver in node.js fundamental error

Tags: node.js, chat

Hello i am running a basic code for a chatserver on node.js. This is almost lifted from the book - Node:Up and Running. The problem is when a client types a message, his message is transmitted at each keystroke, than after a complete line and pressing enter, resulting in output like this -
client1: *(Sends)* Hello
Client2: (Recieves)127.0.0.1:50672>h 127.0.0.1:50672>e 127.0.0.1:50672>l 127.0.0.1:50672>l 127.0.0.1:50672>o

But This is how it SHOULD come
Client2: *(Recieves)* 127.0.0.1:50672>hello

What is happening here is messages are being transmitted at each keystroke, than after pressing enter. I lifted another example code from git by someone and same thing happened! here is my code :

```
var net = require ('net');
var chatServer = net.createServer(),
     clientlist =[];
chatServer.on('connection',function(client){
client.name = client.remoteAddress+':'+client.remotePort;
client.write('Welcome '+ client.name + '!\n');
clientlist.push(client);
client.on('data',function(data){
broadcast(data,client);
});
});
function broadcast(message, client){
 for(var i=0;i<clientlist.length;i+=1){
    if(client !== clientlist[i]){
        clientlist[i].write(client.name + ":"+ message);
    }
    }
    }
console.log("Chatserver Started")
chatServer.listen(9000);
```

Here is the github example which yielded same results:
[GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146)
HOW TO CORRECT THIS BEHAVIOR?

Comment: Include your client javascript. I suspect that your problem is that you are transmitting back to your Node server after each keypress, when you probabyl only want to after the user hits enter (e.keyCode == 13)

Comment: well, the client is just plain old windows command prompt, first i connect using telnet localhost 9000. Then i just type! i do this from one more command prompt to add one more client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server event `data` is fired every time a block of data is received. Probably it fires for every character from the client.

The solution would be to create, in the server's `connection` callback, a buffer string/array. The `data` callback adds the received data to that buffer. When the data contains a newline character, the buffer is broadcasted and emptied.

Comment: hEY thanks this solved the issue. wonder then how the book example is working without this.

Comment: Probably the book works with a unix shell and not windows prompt. Could you maybe accept (and vote?) the answer?